# dataWithContentsOfURL - Received Memory warning handling

Tags: ios, memory-management

I'm working with `ARC`, and using this code for loading data from a 17.4 pdf crypted file.

```
NSData *fileData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:docUrl];
NSMutableData *decPdf = // decrypt using third party library
CFDataRef PDFData = (__bridge CFDataRef)decPdf;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(PDFData);
PDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
```

on iPad1 after a  `Low Memory warning` app crashes on `NSData *fileData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:docUrl]`. Is there something that I can do for managing memory in a better way in this part? If not, how should I handle the memory warning properly for preventing crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick check you can try wrapping the code in a separate `@autoreleasepool{}` block.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSData *fileData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:docUrl];
    NSMutableData *decPdf = // decrypt using third party library
    CFDataRef PDFData = (__bridge CFDataRef)decPdf;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(PDFData);
    PDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
}
```

Comment: I'm not downloading the file, it is a local url

Comment: sometimes it prevents crash, sometimes not. The strange thing is that same code with a larger file, 39 mb, doesn't crash

Comment: @laucel 1. `dataWithContentsOfURL:` will return an autoreleased instance of data. Hence I suggested you create a local autorelease pool by wrapping around that code. 2. I also think that the decryption logic is also creating another copy of same size in the memory causing the app to crash with low memory warning.

Comment: I think the same, but I wanted to solve first my side of the problem, can you tell me why wrapping the cose in an autorelease pool sometimes works and sometimes not? thanks

Comment: Autoreleasepool is nothing but a memory pool which is allocated out of the currently available memory for your application. If at any instant the available memory is less than the required, application crashes because of low memory. Remember runtime memory is shared between various applications running on device.

Comment: Thanks Amar for the explanation, I think that in the end it's problematic to work with large pdf files and `CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider` and there isn't so much to do to prevent low memory issues in this case.